# mongodb replace bsonid to auto inc integer benchmarks

Tags: mongodb, redis

I have researched this topic and still couldn't get a conclusive answer. 
I am wondering weather it's better to replace mongodb _id (BsonObj) to and Auto Inc intger

Since I have read [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) that it's not best practice to replace the _id to an auto inc int

```
Generally in MongoDB, you would not use an auto-increment pattern for the _id field, or any field, because it does not scale for databases
```

I have implemented this using a `_id -> {redis.incr("my_id")}`

and it works, But I am wondering :
1. why did mongo use the Bsson in the first place and why won't they have a build in feature to replace it to auto inc?
2. Do Benchmarks for high scale exists for auto inc integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like they said in the article, using auto-increment keys is not very good for the scalability of the database.

The following points can be mentioned:

- Auto-increment keys tend to localize recently inserted rows/documents in the same page or block in indexed data structures (such as btrees). Many connections inserting data can generate contention. Even very scalable databases (such as Oracle) supporting row level locking are not immune to this problem. This point does not really apply to MongoDB though, since the locking granularity is much worse (database lock).
- Monotonic sequences can trigger data management patterns involving expensive index rebalancing. It depends on the btree implementation, but inserting at one end of a btree while deleting at the other end tend to imbalance the btree.
- In distributed systems based on range partitioning (such as MongoDB when the auto-sharding feature is used), auto-increment keys tend to localize the activity on the same node for recently inserted documents. The workload will apply on one specific shard instead of being distributed on all the shards. It will create a hot spot in the cluster.

Benchmarks are generally useless since they do not apply to your workload. You can build your own benchmark, and if you want to see the negative impact of using monotonic sequences as primary keys, be sure to use many parallel connections to insert data.

Note that in your example, both Redis and MongoDB will tend to serialize the workload, because Redis is single-threaded, and if MongoDB traffic is localized on a single node, you will have contention on the database lock.

If you still want to use auto-increment keys, make sure to avoid sharding on this key, or use a [hashed shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/shard-collection-with-a-hashed-shard-key/).

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.